# In Hibernate, how do you create a composite primary key consisting of foreign keys?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have several link tables for an Any-to-Many relationship about l10n.

I have a table `Foo`, the link table `FooLanguage`, and `Translation` table.

Currently, I have this:

**Foo.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Foo {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FooLanguage> languages;

    // ...
}
```

**FooLanguage.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class FooLaguage {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "translation_id")
    private Translation translation;
}
```

**Translation.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Translation {

    // ...

    // no back refs

    // ...

}
```

This doesn't work as it is asking me for an `IdClass` definition.

Need help, thank you!

Comment: In Foo.java you need to mappedBy column name but I think you are using variable name so Try this way @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo_id") ................and best option if you have database then you can create entities using persistence ...